# Css Error with Parent child

Tags: css, parent-child

I tried to make two sections to my structure, one is a top section and another is a body section.

I'm trying to make the mainbody divs break away from the top section. For some reason when I add the color purple to a main body div it's coloring in everything else!

I added `overflow:hidden` to the wrapper and it did something, am I on the right path?

You can see my example [here](http://www.thomas-walker.com/Test/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you used floating elements and didn't clear after them. Add

```
.mainbody{clear:both;}
```

But why do you have `.topsection{float:left;}`? If `mainbody` has `width: 100%`, it does nothing.

And `overflow:hidden` did somethink because if you have a block element with some floating elements before him, and you set `overflow` different than visible to him, you are creating columns. So then `mainbody` wasn't under `topsection`.

**Edit:**

Even if you remove the nonsense `.topsection{float:left;}`, it won't work because `topright` and `topleft` are not cleared floating elements too. So you have to add `.mainbody{clear:both;}` too, or change your `topsection` into:

```
<div class="topsection">
  <div class="topright">...</div>
  <div class="topleft">...</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And then

```
.clear{clear:both;}
```